# Rails Strong Params not recognizing params sent through Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Hello I am trying to sent the following params from the front end to my backend rails controller where I have strong params set up
My ajax call looks like this

```
$("#send").click(function() {
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var listing_id = $("#listing_id").val();
        d = {
            'message': message, 
            'listing_id': listing_id,
            'status': "pending"
        };

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/crecits",
           data: d
        });
    });
```

This is sending in the following parameter to the controller

```
Parameters: {"message"=>"Hello world", "listing_id"=>"1", "status"=>"some status"}
```

And then my controller that handles this looks like this

```
class CrecitsController < ApplicationController
..
def create
        @crecit = current_user.crecits.new(crecits_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          if @crecit.save
            format.html { redirect_to @crecit, notice: 'Request Sent' }
          else
            format.html { redirect_to listings_path, notice: 'your request can not be sent' }
          end
        end
    end

private
      def crecits_params
         params.require(:crecit).permit(:user_id, :status, :listing_id,    :message)
      end
..
end
```

Comment: Update:
Following is the error message I'm getting
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: crecit):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have params like this:

```
params.require(:crecit).permit(:user_id, :status, :listing_id,    :message)
```

That'll require your params to come in like this:

```
{
  crecit: {
    user_id: ...,
    status: ...,
    etc
  }
}
```

However your AJAX is sending the params without the outer `crecit` hash.

You can either change your AJAX data to send a nested hash, or keep it the same and instead remove the `.require(:crecit)`. I.e. it would just be `params.permit(:user_id, :status, etc)`